# How do I convert a Javascript higher order function to be typescript compliant

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function that is using the filter method to filter our data I need out of an array:

```
const filterFunction = (arr: string[]) => {
  const today = new Date();
  return arr.filter((item:string) => {
    const startDate = new Date(item.contracts[0].startDate);
    const endDate = new Date(item.contracts[0].endDate);
    return startDate <= today && today <= endDate;
  });
};

export default filterFunction;
```

My problem with the code above is the error: property contract does not exist on type string

Comment: Why did you specify `arr: string[]` if it’s not intended to be used on an array of strings? (Also, is this real code and a real error message? The pluralization doesn’t match. Also also, the only “higher-order function” here is `filter`, and it’s not what needs converting.)

Comment: There is no contracts property exist on string type dear. I think you should revise your question

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the type of your parameter. There is no property `contracts` on a string. Change the type of your parameter to something like:

```
arr: { contracts: {startDate: Date; endDate: Date }[] }[]
```

I would recommend you to extract this anonymous type into a named type.